# Split multiple rows into columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot

I have a following `table` :

```
OfficeID    rHour   StHr         EndHr      rdate       rHsDate TACount Proj    HistProj    dayweek
50000       6846    9       9:00 AM      9:59 AM    1/3/2016    NULL    0       0       0            1
50000       6846    10      10:00 AM     10:59 AM   1/3/2016    NULL    0       0       0            1
50000       6847    9       9:00 AM      9:59 AM    1/4/2016    NULL    0       0       0            2
50000       6847    10      10:00 AM     10:59 AM   1/4/2016    NULL    0       0       0            2
50000       6848    9       9:00 AM      9:59 AM    1/5/2016    NULL    0       0       0            3
50000       6848    10      10:00 AM     10:59 AM   1/5/2016    NULL    0       0       0            3
```

My expected output is:

```
OfficeID     rHour  StHr       EndHr    rdate1  rHsDate1    TACount1    Proj1   HistProj1   rdate2  rHsDate2    TACount2    Proj2   HistProj2   rdate3  rHsDate3    TACount3    Proj3   HistProj3
50000         9     9:00 AM    9:59 AM  1/3/2016    NULL    0           0       0           1/4/2016    NULL    0           0       0           1/5/2016    NULL    0           0       0

50000         10    10:00 AM   10:59 AM 1/3/2016    NULL    0           0       0           1/4/2016    NULL    0           0       0           1/5/2016    NULL    0           0        0
```

I Got this result after do a`Self Join` on this `table`. I wonder can I do the same using `pivot`.. Please help ...

Comment: I think you forgot to post your sql...

Comment: i `think` @Jacobr365 is correct

Comment: Yes you can. You reproduce (`rdate, rHsDate, TACount, Proj, HistProj`) 3 times - it is always so or this number is dynamic?

Comment: these numbers are dynamic